# How do you create a weighted graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using the code below, I found out how to make a basic graph data structure, but I want to make it weighted to find shortest paths etc.

```
def generate_edges(graph):
    edges = []

    # for each node in graph
    for node in graph:

        # for each neighbour node of a single node
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            # if edge exists then append
            edges.append((node, neighbour))
    return edges

graph = { "a" : ["c"],
      "b" : ["c", "e"],
      "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
      "d" : ["c"],
      "e" : ["c", "b"],
      "f" : []
    }

print(generate_edges(graph))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the edge a tuple instead of a pair.

Like that: `edges.append((node, neighbour, weight))`.

And I think that each element of the graph list may be on the form: `"a" : [("c", weight)]`

I hope that helps.